# How to add font family to Chart.js V3.7.0

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I tried both this:

```js
plugin: {
  label: {
    font: {
      family: "Lato"
    }
  }
}
```

and this:

```js
myChart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
```

Pieces of code to add `Lato` font family to my chart, but both cases didn't work.

Any better suggestions? Note that the version I use is 3.7.0.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For global use: `Chart.defaults.font.family = "Lato"`.
Details [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html).

Comment: Does this apply for `X` and `Y` `Axes` too?

Comment: Yes, for all labels on the chart.

Comment: Hello, Anton. It seems that no matter the font family that I am trying to apply, when using this option, Text in both `X` and `Y` `Axis` isn't changing. I am a bit experienced with this library and this version, but I struggle a lot to display the correct font family. Is there any other way you can think of, which will Apply the `Lato` font family to the text in `X` and `Y` `Axis`?

Comment: Please check your setup. "Lato" font is not standard and should be provided by the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font_google.asp), like `<head><link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></head>`, **or** by [font-face rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp). I tested it in my sandbox and it is working well with the `Chart.defaults.font.family` property.

Comment: Anton, Thank you so much for the info and your help. Including the file worked like a charm. Keep up with giving great answer!

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to specify would be like this (in `options`):

```js
plugins: { // not plugin
  legend: { // extra layer: legend
    labels: { // with an "s"
      font: {
        family: "Lato" // right here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have disabled `legend` using `display: false` setting. I want to display the `Lato` font-family in text used on `xAxes` and `yAxes`. Is there any other option to achieve this perhaps?